# Why don't we see Janet having rebooting problems after the first time she's rebooted?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-good-place

In *The Good Place*, the first time Janet is rebooted she takes quite a long time to get back to normal; she starts handing people cacti and generally being unhelpful.

But what happened the (at least) 800 other times she was rebooted? Michael reboots her every time they restart the experiment - she's not working directly with him, after all - and it's not shown that she takes any time at all to get back up to speed.

So... does it happen, just off screen? Or does she not need the long time to get back up to speed after that first reboot?

Comment: I haven't seen it, but I'd go with 'movie shorthand'. First time you need to see it all, after that each time the audience has to go through a repetitive cycle it gets shorter. vis Groundhog Day.

Comment: @Tetsujin - it simply doesn't come up, and there have been "rebootings" sometimes multiple in a day

Answer (score 5):

It's partly because it happens off-screen, but also Janet becomes more advanced each time she is rebooted, and that probably allows her to recover from rebooting more easily. We see a similar phenomenon with Derrick; at first, he is of very low intelligence, but when we see him in a later season, he's capable of more advanced conversations. He also seems to be only mildly inconvenienced for a short time when he's rebooted, and Mindy has clearly become rather cavalier about it.